# MongoDB - get another field's value without updating

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, conditional-operator

When running a mongoDB find query, in some special cases I want to return the value of another field, but without updating the original one.

A client is searching for counselors in a specific price range. Some counselors are doing in person counseling, others for just virtual. Some counselors have a fixed price (field: price), others have different prices for in-person and virtual counseling (fields: in_person_price, virtual_price). In that case, their "price" field is set to 0, and that will make the query choose another field to display.

There will be an external variable "in_person" which is true or false, which determines what price the client sees when searching.

So, for example, if a counselor's "price" is 0, the "in_person_price" is 145, and the "virtual_price" is 90...

If the "in_person" variable is marked as true, the "price" returned by the mongoDB query will be 145

If the "in_person" variable is marked as false, the "price" returned by the mongoDB query will be 90

Here is the query in pseudocode:

db.counselors.find({price:
//if the "price" field is 0... { if "in_person" is true, return in_person_price, else return virtual_price } else return price
})

so how do I translate this thought into a viable mongoDB query?

Comment: can you re-write the question using real JSON documents, and the expected outputs for those cases? check aggregation and `$cond` it might help you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M4WEnojprK_).

With "aggregation" instead of "find" you could do what you need. There you can put conditions and transform your data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "price": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$price",
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": false,  // Here you should insert that in_person variable in your code
              "then": "$in_person_price",
              "else": "$virtual_price"
            }
          },
          "else": "$price"
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Excellent, that works. Now... how would I go about performing a find on it afterwards? I tried to use a query on it, and the query behaves as though it was still the original data.

Comment: For example, if I use "db.collections.aggregate(*the syntax you wrote here*).find(price: {$lte: 40}), it *still* behaves as though the price was 0, even though it's changed.

Comment: This wont change the original values, just perform some transform operations. You could add a $match operation inside te aggregation and It Will be executed on the transformed documents. Just add {$match:{price: {$lte: 40}} at the end of the array.

Comment: @IanMcInnes I'm answering This from mu phone if you need an example i could update the main answer later.

Comment: @IanMcInnes here it is a playground with what you ask. https://mongoplayground.net/p/I_PfdloWikG